# ag-grid enterprise not displaying for Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid

I used ag-grid community version for Angular without no problem, then I needed to use the "tree-grid" function of the enterprise version so I installed ag-grid-enterprise, however, I never got it to work. I got a trial key, so I don't get any errors in the console.
I followed the first example here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/ but the table isn't showing, it looks like this: 
[Tree grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeRWO.png)

I have tried install and re-install the ag-angular, ag-community and ag-enterprise, so that this is how it looks in the package.json file.

```html
    "ag-grid-angular": "^23.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^23.0.1",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^23.0.1",
```

Has anybody else experienced a similar problem when switching to enterprise version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure in your AG Grid component, you import the enterprise edition.

```
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
```

Comment: I do that in my app.component.ts file as in the example!

Comment: Oh.. Acording to the picture, you just need to specify a height for the grid and then it will show up.